# Is it okay to call SDL_RenderCopy() for each sprite?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

This is a followup to my question here: [Is it okay to have a SDL_Surface and SDL_Texture for each sprite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66267674/is-it-okay-to-have-a-sdl-surface-and-sdl-texture-for-each-sprite/66294761#66294761)

I made an class called entity each having a SDL_Texture, which is set in the constructor and then a member function render() is called for every onscreen entity in a vector, which uses SDL_RenderCopy() to draw to the renderer.

This render() function includes generating rectangles for each sprite based on their position/cameradata

Is this okay? Is there a faster way?

I made a testlevel with 96 sprites that each take up 2% of the screen with tons of overdraw and ft is 15ms (~65fps)at a resolution of1600x900. Seems a little slow for just some sprites, and my computer breathes much heavier then when playing a full game such as spelunky or isaac.

Comment: If you are using [VSYNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing#Vertical_synchronization) by using the flag `DL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC` in the function `CreateRenderer`, then this could explain why you are limited to about 60 FPS despite rendering only 96 sprites. However, this does not explain why your computer is, as you say, "breathing heavily". However, I wouldn't pay much attention to this, as this could have several reasons, which may be beyond your control. What you should mainly pay attention to is the FPS.

Comment: That's the only way of drawing SDL provides, you could only cache result or manipulate inputs. Internally newer SDL batches multiple draws into one, but it is limited by what you feed into its input. If you can calculate which parts are definitely invisible - do that and don't draw them. If you know you images don't have transparency (or other way to ensure visibility) - render them front-to-back to reduce overdraw. Also packing images into atlases coud significantly reduce texture changes and hence give better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Prefer frame time over FPS**

You want to measure and judge your performance based on the frame time not FPS. Because the relation between the two is not linear. Going from 20 FPS to 30 FPS needs about 16.7 ms worth of optimization. That is the same amount of performance gain in optimization it takes to get from 30 FPS to 60 FPS. So if you judge performance based on FPS you would come to conclusion that a particular "optimization" that increased the FPS from 30 to 60 is better that the one that made a 20 FPS scene run 31 FPS. while the latter is actually a better optimization.

**Batch your draws**

If you pack all your textures into one and store each individual image's coordinates, you can use the same texture to draw many of your objects. This is limited by the size and number of your textures and also the maximum texture size supported in your environment. In my experiences 4096x4096 is safe but I prefer to use 2048x2048 "texture atlases". There are many utility programs to make such textures. You can easily find a suitable one by doing a Google search.

In this setup in addition to a SDL texture, each sprite also has the x, y, width and height of the region in the "big" texture containing the particular image needed. You can make a `TextureRegion` class. Each sprite then has a `TextureRegion`. This whole process is often referred to as batching. Look it up. The whole idea is to minimize state changes. I am not sure if it applies to software rendering or to all of SDL2 backends.

**Cache your transformations**

Batching your sprites will increase the performance in the GPU side. The CPU bound code is another optimization opportunity. Instead of calculating the parameters of `SDL_RenderCopy` in each frame, calculate them once and cache them. Then when the position/rotation of the camera or object changes, recalculate the cache. You can do this in "accessors" of your entity class (like `setPosition`, `setRotaion`, etc..). Note that instead of directly recalculating transform as soon as a position or rotation changes your want to flag the object as "dirty" and check for the dirty flag in the your render function. if `this->isDirty` Then recalculate and cache the transform. This prevents redundant calculations when you do this:

```
//if dirty flag is not used each of the following function calls
//would have resulted in a recalculation of transforms. However by
//using the dirty flag they will be calculated only once before 
//the rendering of next frame in the render() function.
player->setPostion(start_x,start_y);
player->setRotation(0);
camera->reset();
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you very much! I will try to implement these.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've done some more testing by examining the memory/cpu usage of this program at full screen with a "demanding" level and managed to make it similar to other games by **enforcing a framerate cap** with SDL_Wait()

```
float g_max_framerate = 60;
float g_max_frametime = 1/g_max_framerate * 1000;
...
while (!quit) { 
        
        lastticks = ticks;
        ticks = SDL_GetTicks();
        elapsed = ticks - lastticks;
        
        ...
        
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        //lock framerate
        if(elapsed < g_max_frametime) {
            SDL_Delay(g_max_frametime - elapsed);
        }
}
```

With this limitation it is appropriatly lowspec.

Comment: In your question, you stated that the FPS was already in the range of about 60 FPS, which is normal. Therefore, reducing the frame rate further does not seem to be the solution to your problem. However, I believe having a frame rate limiter is always a good idea, to prevent excessive frame rates (>150 FPS).

Comment: Yes, for this reason I will not accept my own answer. However, this did get the CPU from 30% down to 3%, thus stopping my computer from heating up and blowing its fans loudly.